# Pipeline failed after implementing MFA

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, multi-factor-authentication

I have made a few pipelines in Azure Data Factory, which transfer and modify data from Blob Storage (Excel Files) to Azure SQL. They were off for like 2 month and the company has implemented MFA on whole Azure Active Directory.

After that when I try to run the pipelines I have only "Failed status". For every pipeline the error is the same. They are look like this:

*Operation on target Data flow1 failed: {"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: java.lang.Exception: fail to reach https://we.frontend.clouddatahub.net/subscriptions/aa2d32bf-f0d0-4656-807b-7e929da73853/entities/99264214-3071-4faa-87c2-32d9dec7e5a4/identities/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/token?api-version=2.0 with status code:403, payload:{"error":{"code":"ManagedIdentityInvalidCredential","message":"Acquire MI token from AAD failed. ErrorCode: invalid_client, Message: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details. You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS700027: Client assertion failed signature validation.\r\nTrace ID: 4eef805e-a0ca-494e-bcc2-c01cd755f400\r\nCorrelation ID: f313ba30-9455-4065-90ab-a0fe28dadc99\r\nTimestamp: 2022-02-21 13:11:56Z","details":[],"additionalInfo":[]}}, CorrelationId:171b73ff-5721-45e5-bf95-2b29dc4dd1b4, RunId:887b22ec-6cae-42d3-9580-b93a98800b3c","Details":"java.lang.Exception: fail to reach https://we.frontend.clouddatahub.net/subscriptions/aa2d32bf-f0d0-4656-807b-7e929da73853/entities/99264214-3071-4faa-87c2-32d9dec7e5a4/identities/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/token?api-version=2.0 with status code:403, payload:{"error":{"code":"ManagedIdentityInvalidCredential","message":"Acquire MI token from AAD failed. ErrorCode: invalid_client, Message: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details. You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS700027: Client assertion failed signature validation.\r\nTrace ID: 4eef805e-a0ca-494e-bcc2-c01cd755f400\r\nCorrelation ID: f313ba30-9455-4065-90ab-a0fe28dadc99\r\nTimestamp: 2022-02-21 13:11:56Z","details":[],"additionalInfo":[]}}, CorrelationId:171b73ff-5721-45e5-bf95-2b29dc4dd1b4, RunId:887b22ec-6cae-42d3-9580-b93a98800b3c\n\tat com.microsoft.datafactory.dat"}*

Is there any way I can evade this error without deactivating MFA?

Comment: What account is used to authenticate?  It obviously can't be one that requires MFA, so you may need to use a Managed Identity or provision a Service Principal to authenticate.  And of course you can switch the auth to SQL Auth for SQL Server and SAS/Account Key auth for Azure Storage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will change the account and I hope this will be working. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [David Browne - Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/david-browne-microsoft) for your valuable suggestion. Posting your suggestion as answer to help other community members.

> Use either of `Managed identity` or `Provision a Service principle`
> for authentication. Switch the Authentication to `SQL Auth for SQL Server` and `SAS/Account Key auth for Azure Storage`.